# Why do I get a different git status in a shared folder when logged in on a local VM?

Tags: git, macos, centos, virtual-machine

I am working on an OS/X machine, and I have a CentOS 7 VM that I run on there. I have set up a separate (case-sensitive) partition on my drive with a folder that is shared between the two machines so that I can work within OS/X, but build in CentOS. I have Reasons.

This is almost always not an issue. However, it seems that I have run into something strange with respect to a specific git repository:

If I run `git status` in the OS/X terminal, I get a clean repository:

```sh
$ git status
On branch 3.2.1
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/3.2.1'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

However, if I run the exact same command in the VM, I get the following:

```sh
$ git status
On branch 3.2.1
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/3.2.1'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   some/file

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

What exactly is happening here? Note that the changes are substantive changes; there is another question on here about line endings, and that is not the difference it claims to find here.

(For some context: I only noticed this because I made changes in the VM, committed them, and pushed them all from within the VM; However, VS Code claimed that I had not made those changes, and that was consistent with what I saw on the remote afterwards. Having then committed and pushed those changes from OS/X, now the VM thinks that something funny is up. Looking at the output from `git diff`, it does not match the current version of the file: i.e. the last commit deleted a few lines, but git diff seems to think I have added them back:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/some/file b/some/file
index 8444607..d42b59a 100644
--- a/some/file
+++ b/some/file
@@ -167,6 +167,9 @@ 
... snip ...
+
+Lines that were deleted in the last commit
+Another line that was deleted in the last commit
 A line that is in the current file
```

)

(Some additional information, in case this is relevant: this is all within a git submodule of another module)

Comment: Is it really a shared partition ? or just a shared folder ? What is the filesystem of this partition ?

Comment: Can you add the output of `ls -l some/file` and `ls -l .git/index` run from both systems to your question ? (note : I'm not very familiar with submodules, perhaps a submodule has a separate index file hidden somewhere under `.git/` ...)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. It's a shared folder in a separate partition. I will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: For submodules, the git history is stored in the parent .git folder, under `.git/modules/$module`. So running `ls -l some/file` and `ls -l ../.git/modules/$module/index` reveals the same in both cases.

Comment: It could also be an issue with each system's io buffers, which may be out of sync with the content on the actual partition. If you see another instance of this issue, try running a command like `sync` on one system and see if it changes things for what the other system sees (try this both ways)

Comment: I have tried running `sync` on both systems, but it has made no difference.

Comment: Your description seems to indicate that OSX and your VM do not see the same version of `some/file` : do `cat some/file` or `less some/file` show the same content on both systems ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221251/discussion-between-simon-rose-and-legec).

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, in case someone else runs into this: It appears that this was some issue with some kind of file buffering on the two OSs. When I added new data in OS/X and saved it, both CentOS and OS/X agreed on the file contents. I'm not sure why they became out of sync, but making an explicit change and saving it seems to have fixed it.