# Vscode integrated terminal working differently than Linux terminal with git

Tags: linux, git, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am running into weird issue with Vscode integrated terminal.
It cannot find a git repository, while my normal linux terminal finds it perfectly fine.

Below image clearly tells the problem. What might be the issue here?
[image]

Comment: Can you `ping https://github.com` from integrated terminal?

Comment: ping is successful.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. On my normal terminal git works perfectly fine, but on the integrated terminal I cannot push, pull, fetch etc. One thing to notice is that my repository is private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and what worked for me is to disable **Git: Terminal Authentication** in the settings. It will prompt the username and the password in the terminal. Hope that this solution/workaround is good for other people.

From this site I found this solution/workaround:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136970

Answer (score 0):

I have had a few strange issues with VSCode git integration versus working in the integrated terminal.

For example, sometimes the git integration in VSCode and and in the terminal disagree with each other, and sometimes the terminal's history is apparently corrupted by VS Code. See my question here: [Why do I get a different git status in a shared folder when logged in on a local VM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63815075/why-do-i-get-a-different-git-status-in-a-shared-folder-when-logged-in-on-a-local)

I haven't entirely sorted out why this occurs, so I can't guarantee that it is the same problem as you are finding, but it could be related.

Comment: It seems in your case VM (and two separate OS) is involved. But not in my case. Thanks though.

Comment: That was true, but I think it is possible that VSCode's git integration does some strange things when you are also interacting in the terminal. I never did completely resolve the why in that case, but I do think that it was more than just the VM vs host issue.